# How to "overwrite" in a single commit a git repo with another repo

Tags: git, github, controls, version

We've got two separate git repos, let's call them DEV and LIVE. Lots of commits happen in DEV. Occasionally, we want to take DEV and overwrite LIVE with it, in a single commit (not preserving the entire history and seeing all the historical commits in LIVE).

What is the simplest and safest way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a "release" branch which you can use to push from `DEV` to `LIVE`.

All you would then need to do (when you want to update `LIVE`) is to merge `master` into `release` (which generates one `commit`), and push that `release` branch.

```
git remote add LIVE /url/to/LIVE/repo.git
git fetch LIVE
git checkout master

# would work if there were already a release branch in LIVE
git branch -u LIVE/release release master
# otherwise, just create a local one
git branch release master

# ... do some commit

# when ready to deliver
git checkout release
git merge master

# first push to LIVE
git push -u LIVE release
# if there were already a release branch in LIVE
git push
```

Comment: Many thanks VonC! I'm kind of new to Git, would you be so kind as to list out the commands I'd need to use?

Comment: @AntoineA. Sure, I have edited the answer with the requested command. The idea is to keep a release branch in order to record the releases (as one merged commit).

Comment: Thanks VonC! Just to be clear, those commands would be in which repo?

Comment: In DEV, before pushing to LIVE

Comment: Is the last line what pushes from DEV to LIVE? shouldn't we replace 'origin' with a remote created from DEV to LIVE?

Comment: OK I think I get it. The 'release' branch you create tracks a remote (LIVE). So first you would do something like this in DEV:  
`git remote add Live <path to live repo>  
git branch -u Live/release release`  
  
Now the release branch can push to the remote LIVE. And the final line would be:  
`git push -u Live release`

Is that correct?

Comment: @AntoineA. Yes, if you want to call your remote Live, it would work like you said. I have edited the answer.